# TabBar selection changes instead of rendering the desired View

Tags: iphone, swiftui, navigation

So the thing is I got this application, that I am writing (Using Swift 5.7, Xcode 14.2 and SwiftUI) that has a bunch of views that need to interact. This is a graphical idea of the Views I am working with:

[image: application view schema]

When the app Starts `ContentView` is the first View to be rendered on screen. This is the code that initiates it:

```
var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup {
        NavigationView {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
```

At the same time, `ContentView` has a TabBar where it contains 3 other views (one for each button of the TabBar): 1. OnlineDeviceView 2. VideoListView 3. ConfigurationView this views are accesible. This is the code for those views:

```
TabView {
                OnlineDevicesView(viewModel: viewModel)
                    .tabItem {
                        Image(systemName: "video.fill")
                        Text("Record")
                    }
                VideoListView()
                    .tabItem {
                        Image(systemName: "airplayvideo")
                        Text("Videos")
                    }
                ConfigurationView()
                    .tabItem {
                        Image(systemName: "person.fill")
                        Text("Configuration")
                    }
            }.navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
        }
```

and finally I have the following code inside the `VideoView`

```
var body: some View {
    if shouldPlayVideo {
        NavigationLink(destination:  VideoView(videoUrl: URL(string: theVideoUrl ?? "")!), isActive: self.$shouldPlayVideo) { EmptyView()}
    }else{
        List($videos, id: \.self ) { video in
            HStack {
                Image(systemName: "film")
                if let creationDate = video.attributes[.creationDate].wrappedValue as? Date {
                    Text(dateFormatter.string(from: creationDate))
                        .onTapGesture {
                            shouldPlayVideo = true
                            theVideoUrl = video.url.wrappedValue
                        }
                } else {
                    Text("Unknown creation date")
                }
            }.navigationBarTitle("Videos")
        }
```

And, what seems to be the problem? Well, when the List inside VideoView  is rendered and the user taps on any video on the List, **the apps navigates to the first Tab (OnlineDevicesView) instead of showing the `VideoView`** (which is basically a video Player). But if I tap in the tab corresponding to ViewListView (the second Tab) I finally do get to the the VideoView containing the Video Player.

Here you can see a video of what I mean:

[Here you will be able to find a GIF of the actual app failing.](https://www.landhsoft.com/iphone_bug.gif) (I could not add it directly to this question because it's bigger than the allowed 2MB)